# Representing textual solution to problem using Math notation

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

If I person $A$ & $B$ both have $40$ dollars, how much must $A$ give $B$ so that B has $10$ dollars more that $A$?

Answer is $5$ dollars. $A$ now has $35$ dollars while $B$ has $4$5 dollars. How to represent this question and answer mathematically?

This probably way off the mark but something like?:

$$40 + 40 = x + 40 + 10$$

Comment: Question's not clear. Maybe 40 + 40 = 35 + 45?

Comment: Let the answer be $x$. Then how much money does A wind up with? how much money does B wind up with? how do you write down B has \$$10$ more than A?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I removed my "spoiler of an answer" in respect of your much more constructive socratic approach ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let A have $a$ dollars and B have $b$ dollars. When A gives $x$ dollars to B then A will have $a'=a-x$ dollars, and B will have $b'=b+x$ dollars. Now we want $$b'=a'+10\ ,$$
which translates into
$$b+x=a-x+10\ .$$
Solving for $x$ we obtain
$$x={1\over2}(a-b+10)\ ,$$
whatever the initial values $a$ and $b$ are. E.g., if $a=15$ and $\>b=41$
then we obtain $$x={1\over2}(15-41+10)=-8\ .$$ This means that A has to *receive* $8$ dollars from B in order that the "closing" condition is met.